im not able to run android emulator with vs code
enter image description here
I reinstalled java and still nothing happened, still the same problem persists. How to solve it ?
What caused the problem, who knows the problem and how to solve it?
I am using openjdk version "21.0.3" 2024-04-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.3+9 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.3+9 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
 Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Veeraphong\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34-ext8, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11572160)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.8.1)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.8.34316.72
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11572160)

[√] VS Code (version 1.89.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Veeraphong\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.90.0


did you add jdk path in your environment variables?
